# Число не преобразуется в строку. JS

Tags: javascript

Есть массив объектов с полями name, phone.
Значения в поле phone через цикл хочу преобразовать в строку. Содержатся там только цифры.
Пробовал и String() и .toString(). и +"".

```
for (index in contactList){
  contactList[index].phone = String(contactList[index].phone);
  console.log(typeof contactList[index].phone);
}            
console.log(contactList);
```

В цикле выводит, что формат String. Но когда вывожу весь массив phone выводится числом.
https://gyazo.com/e5a4d1c84e820aa9c167aff0e6f81aa5

Comment: Создайте [воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш `contactList` меняется где-то в непоказанном коде (возможно - асинхронно), и в консоли Вы видите обновленные объекты.

```js
var contactList = [
  { name: "John", phone: 1234567890, contactSequence: 1 },
  { name: "Test", phone: 4444444444, contactSequence: 2 }
];

console.log(contactList);
for (var index in contactList){
  contactList[index].phone = String(contactList[index].phone);
  console.log(typeof contactList[index].phone);
}            
console.log(contactList);
```

Comment: Спасибо, нужно было сразу отдельно проверить. Буду копать...